# What does "soft" mean?

Tags: meaning

In drama movie *Bombshell (2019)*, Fox CEO Roger Ailes questions Megan Kelly about how she upset Donald Trump:

> Megyn Kelly: Roger, we had a full-screen of Ivana's recantation. Which
> is **soft**.
>
> Roger Ailes: She accused him during a divorce.
>
> Megyn Kelly: Well, his lawyer, Michael Cohen, claims you can't rape a
> spouse.  It pissed me off.

What does "soft" mean? I assume it means weak or in this context not convincing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "cowardly" in this context.

Backing down in the face of robust opposition, rather than standing up and holding your position. Instead of holding to what she had said previously, she backed down and recanted.

"Weak" can indeed be used if you like.

Some may argue it can mean "stupid", as in "soft in the head", but I think "cowardly" is more likely here.